# Как защитить файл include от прямого вызова?

Tags: .htaccess, php, include, javascript

Если в папку c инклудами кинуть `.htaccess deny from all` то `JS`, также не могут вытянуть его оттуда. Как правильно организовать защиту?

Точнее как защитить те файлы которые вызываются посредством AJAX запроса. Чтобы через сайт можно было вызвать страницу а напрямик выдавало что ошибка либо редирект поставить..

Comment: А чего это JS у вас тянут оттуда php-шные includы?
Разнести по папкам то, что нужно клиенту (JS) и серверу (.php) трудно?

Comment: Тянут они странички для AJAX но я не хочу чтобы к ним можно было обратится напрямую.

Comment: Обращайтесь через скрипт. Пусть он только инициализирует нужные вам переменные (например, для защиты скриптов как в Джумле), а потом подтягивает запрошенный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Права на файлы, вызываемые AJAX'ом, поставьте 644

Comment: не не пашет все равно в браузере открывается при прямом запросе.

Comment: Как вариант, можно ajax запросом передавать переменную(test), неважно какую, а в файле-обработчике запроса делать так:

   `if (!isset($_POST['test'])) exit();`

Comment: А вот это вариант очень хороший!

Comment: Ну тогда "Принять ответ!" и будьте здоровы! %)

Comment: Выставил два плюса)  
Получается что то вроде капчи.  
А если ещё этот код генерировать в md5 и на стороне его расшифрововать...

Comment: Ну тут уже насколько фантазии хватит )))

Comment: Да идеально. как сам не допер если можно через defined защитить инклуды то и здесь аналогично. Зачет!

Comment: Ну вот. И человек теперь уверен, что он надежно защитился. Как будто нельзя подделать post-запрос.

Comment: можно подделать я это понимаю. главное было скрыть от интересующихся)) а если есть решение для очень интересующихся я только за узнать)

Answer (score 0):

Вызывая include-файл, прежде проверьте DEFINE. Например, аякс-запрос делайте к файлу index.php, а в index.php за-define-те переменную.

index.php

```
<?php
define ('DEFTEST', true);
....
?>
```

в иклюд файлах проверяйте DEFTEST:

```
<?php
 if (!defined("DEFTEST")) die("Access denied!");
....
?>
```

Comment: Нет это не канает для AJAX. для простых инклудов работает если вызывать через ajax будет die

Answer (score 0):

Можно все include поместить в отдельную директорию и закинуть в нее .htaccess (deny from all).
А для их использования через Ajax, создать отдельный роутер в корне (ajax.php), который сам будет отправлять и получать данные от обработчиков в include.

Comment: А здесь получается оброботчик ajax.php будет получать POST донные и в зависимости от них инклудить в себя нужные файлы. Если я правильно понял то тут также можно подделать POST запрос.

Comment: Ваш вопрос звучит "Как защитить файл include от прямого вызова?" - это действие полностью выполняется.

>то также можно подделать POST запрос
Его и в обычном вызове можно подделать! Все нужно проверять на корректность, в нашем случае либо в роутере либо в файлах инклюда.

Comment: Ну так за этим и спрашиваю! Буду очень признателен посмотреть пример или почитать если скините ссылку.

Comment: Данные на корректность проверяются просто:
Чаще всего это либо числовые либо текстовые.
числовые - вырезка всего что не число, если передаются заранее известные числа, то проверить и ошибка если число не то.
строковые - вырезка тегов и всяких других не нужных вам символов.
Так же проверка адреса с которого был отправлен запрос.